# Can't retrieve Outlook internal emails with labels using Python pywin32

Tags: python, vba, outlook, com, pywin32

I'm trying to use Python to access Outlook. The code I've learnt from several sources looks like this:

```
# Import packages
import os
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Initiate an Outlook session
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Specify the folder
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
InboxMessages = inbox.Items

# Apply filters
ReceivedDateTime = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
InboxMessages = [message for message in InboxMessages if message.ReceivedTime.timestamp() >= ReceivedDateTime.timestamp()]
InboxMessages = [message for message in InboxMessages if message.SenderEmailAddress.__contains__('mycompany.com')]
```

It almost works, except for one problem with the condition that filters sender email addresses. In particular, if I specify this condition with emails from my company, it only returns a part of company emails I've got in my Inbox, but not all as it's supposed to.

I take a look at the list and it appears that emails not being returned are those with a label that we use to assign to the emails. They may be important or not so, from Casual, Hangout, Urgent, etc. Regardless, if it's assigned a label, it's not returned. On the other hand, all company emails without labels are returned. Again, it doesn't matter who send those mails or how important they are. Also, there doesn't seem such a problem with emails from external sources.

My question is what could potentially lead to this result, like a security encryption? And is there a way to get around it, or do I need to ask IT for some help?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, never loop through all messages in a folder, you'd never create a SELECT SQL query without a WHERE clause, would you? Use [Items.Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict) or `Items.Find/FindNext` - let the store provider do the job.

Secondly, internal messages sent between two mailboxes have `"EX"` type sender address (`MailItem.SenderEmailType == "EX"`), not `"SMTP"`. Create a restriction on the `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F"`) - take a look a message with [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author, click IMessage button).

Your query would be like the following (it specifies `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME`, `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress`, and `PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS` DASL property names):

```
@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040" > '2022-07-19' AND ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F" LIKE '%@mycompany' OR "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001F" LIKE '%@mycompany.com')
```